# Capture raw video byte stream for real time transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, gstreamer, squid

I would like to achieve the following:

Set up a proxy server to handle video requests by clients (for now, say all video requests from any Android video client) from a remote video server like YouTube, Vimeo, etc. I don't have access to the video files being requested, hence the need for a proxy server. I have settled for Squid. This proxy should process the video signal/stream being passed from the remote server before relaying it back to the requesting client.

To achieve the above, I would either

## 1. Need to figure out the precise location (URL) of the video resource being requested, download it really fast, and modify it as I want before HTTP streaming it back to the client as the transcoding continues (simultaneously, with some latency)

## 2. Access the raw byte stream, pipe it into a transcoder (I'm thinking ffmpeg) and proceed with the streaming to client (also with some expected latency).

Option #2 seems tricky to do but lends more flexibility to the kind of transcoding I would like to perform. I would have to actually handle raw data/packets, but I don't know if ffmpeg takes such input.

In short, I'm looking for a solution to implement real-time transcoding of videos that I do not have direct access to from my proxy. Any suggestions on the tools or approaches I could use? I have also read about Gstreamer (but could not tell if it's applicable to my situation), and MPlayer/MEncoder.

And finally, a rather specific question: Are there any tools out there that, given a YouTube video URL, can download the byte stream for further processing? That is, something similar to the Chrome YouTube downloader but one that can be integrated with a server-side script?

Thanks for any pointers/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should ask single coding questions. What you asked is more like a general "how would a write my application". A few comments though:

- squid is a http proxy, video use usually streamed over e.g. rtsp.
- yes there are tools that grab the rtsp url from a youtube url, be sure to understand the terms of use for the video servie before going that way though.
- gstreamer has a gst-rtsp-server module that contains a rtsp server, that also can be used as a proxy for a given rtsp stream.